# Noise in audio received through TCP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to send an audiofile from raspberry pi to PC. I was successfully able to send and receive the file. But while playing the received file there is some noise present. Also the audio seems to drag a bit as well. The file is showing same size as the original file. When i tested the same in loop back mode in PC, it works fine without any noise. How resolve this issue? Please help

Comment: If you received noise via TCP, it was transmitted.

Comment: "*The file is showing same size as the original file.*" are all the bytes identical as well?

Comment: Are you using the TCP to stream the audio? Or are you transmitting the file and then play it on the other end?
The main reason why RTP protocol runs over UDP is that streaming requires low latency and will get scrambled due to re-transmits, and TCP overhead might cause issues with continuity.
If you're saving to file and play on the other side, check the data integrity (`md5sum`) and see what data is lost (and then figure out why)

Comment: @alk: I compared the original file with the received file. It seems that after a chunk of data that is actually send, some of the data thats already received is repeated. And i believe this is the noise in the audio file. About the size, the size is same, but a lot of actual data is lost. ie. only a part of the audio is being received.

Comment: @immortal : We are transmitting the file and then playing it on the other end.

Comment: If the data in the file received is different from the original file *and* the transmission was done using TCP then the receiving and/or sending code is broken.

Comment: @sms If one of the sides is running a Windows based OS, please make sure you open the files with `rb`/`wb` and not `r`/`w` permissions as Windows sometimes adds a Carriage return (`\r`) character before a Line Feed (`\n`) character automatically.
That apart something in your code is broken. Use something like beyond compare to see the differences in your file contents.